# Salesforce - Invalid constructor name error

Tags: class, constructor, controller, salesforce, apex-code

I'm building a controller to show the data from a custom object on a Visualforce page. Here's my class:

```
public class myController {

    Opportunity opp;
    list<Leg__c> legs;

    public Opportunity getOpp() {
        if(opp == null)
            opp = [select name, Primary_Contact__r.name, Primary_Contact__r.email, Primary_Contact__r.phone from Opportunity
                where id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
        return opp;
    }
    public getLegs() {
        legs = [select Departure__c, Arrival__c from Leg__c
                where Opportunity__c = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
    }

}
```

I can't get it to compile! I keep getting

> Error: myController Compile Error: Invalid constructor name: getLegs at line 12 column 12

What am I doing wrong, and how can this be solved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have a function `public getLegs()` because it doesn't specify a return type, it thinks its a constructor, but has the wrong name, so the error is somewhat misleading, the actual problem is that the getLegs() function doesn't say what its return type is, it should e `public List<Leg__c> getLegs()` (and you need to add a `return legs`)

Comment: Perfect! I didn't realize I was actually supposed to be using a function (VERY new to apex haha)